# Are questions about impacts of cultural, economical and political parameters on math education on-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions, question-standards, questions

Math education as a social activity has an undeniable mutual interaction with almost all social parameters like cultural, economical and political changes in a society. For example [John Smith](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/555/john-smith)'s answer to my question "[*Mathematics Education in Africa*](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/mathematics-education-in-africa/1135?noredirect=1#comment2073_1135)" shows a direct relevance between political problems in African countries and problems in developing mathematical research.

**Question.** Are (historical, reference request, etc.) questions about the impacts of cultural, economical and political parameters on math education in different societies on-topic in MESE? If yes, what is a suitable tag for such questions?

---

Here is a (not too exact) example of such questions.

---

**Example.**

It seems Soviet Union scientific policies was really successful in improving math education.

**Question.** Is there any research to compare the status of math education and math research in Russia during communist regime and after that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what kinds of questions you have in mind here.  Could you provide some examples?

Comment: @JimBelk I added an example.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in principle such questions can be on-topic. Of course, the usual restrictions regarding especially (but not limited too) 'opinion based' and 'too broad' apply.

Moreover, it should be noted that to ask such question in a way suitable for this site will typically need some pre-existing expertise on the asker's side, likely more so than for more hands-on questions. Too many broad and vague questions, possibly based on false or dubious premises, would in my opinion not be a good way to develop the site.

Comment: What about tags?

Comment: I do not think there needs to be one tag for all these questions. I could  imagine things like historical-development (history is already used somewhat differently) education-policy or socioeconomic-context

Comment: Maybe it is unrelated to this post but (fortunately/unfortunately) it seems I am changing the culture of the forum really! Some users (e.g. Markus Klein) are asking questions frequently (3 per day) and some others are posting Saint Georgian questions with an explicit religious theme! (e.g. [This post](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/when-asked-to-by-a-religious-university-how-can-an-instructor-make-a-mathematic) by Brian Rushton).

Comment: "Maybe"? It seems pretty clear this is unrelated to this post. :-)

Comment: (My last comment here) What we need is a moderator to manage this chaos! **A Man Who Never Asks a Question!** (because he knows all answers!) :-)

Comment: @SaintGeorg That question was one that came up pretty often when I worked at BYU. So it is not hypothetical, although I have written hypothetical questions.